# Deploying multiple blogs, or something like yammer

Tags: php, mysql, database

How would you theoretically go about deploying multiple blogs (in the hundreda) or something like Yammer where you get 1 environement per company with a custom platform.

I have a project where I need this kind of architecture and I can't decide what I should do with my database,

1 table for all articles or create dynamically tables for each blog? 
Or create a new database for each blog?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on the same scenario, although NOT like a microblog (Yammer, Twitter, etc). The basic storage is to have the Blog as its own entity or table. You then have a user or users that can publish to that blog.

In Yammer, you have the user with his "blog", you then have a higher container that allows multiple users to belong to a "blog". To mirror this in a database, you have the concept of the "user blog" and one of a "organizational blog", which contains many "user blogs".

Hope this helps.